# How to set Object-array default event representation

Tags: esper, nesper

I'm facing an error while I change the default event representation to Object array in this way:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.getEngineDefaults().getEventMeta().setDefaultEventRepresentation(EventUnderlyingType.OBJECTARRAY);
```

My events definitions are in create schema way. The epl file get successfully deploy, but when I insert a new Object[] event, an error rise telling that there are no event definition for this event name.

If more details are needed, please, ask for it.

Comment: Provide the complete code that reproduces the issue and the full exception text + stack trace.

Comment: Is necessary to define every event type when the default event represetation is set to object array??

Comment: It is necessary to define at least the name of an event type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tests, I can say that it's necessary to define every event type when the default event representation is set to object array.